# reorder database when reorder UitableView cell

Tags: ios, sqlite, uitableview

i am using reordering in UITableView in iOS. i want that my database should also reorder when i reorder in UITableView cell. I am not able to find anything helpful tutorials till now. How can i make changes in database with change in order in UITableview. please help.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We encourage you to [research your questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). If you've [tried something already](http://whathaveyoutried.com/), please add it to the question - if not, research and attempt your question first, and then come back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont think there is any in built way to do this.

You can do something like this.

1.Add new column and name it some thing like 'order' or 'sort'

2.insert sequence number in this 1,2 ,3 ....

3.when u change order in UITableView update this column.

4.now when u select data sort it by this column